# crontab: "ftp command not found" error in macos

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, cron, ftp

Newb here. I've been looking for solutions about this but I can't seem to find one.

**Error log from my crontab:**

```
/Users/harrold/bin/ftp_automate.sh: line 14: ftp: command not found
```

I have made a script named `ftp_automate.sh` sending files to my ftp server from my local folder. **The script works in terminal**(zsh) with `% sh ftp_automate.sh`. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# FTP server details here
SERVER="ftp.DUMMYSITE.com"
USERNAME="DUMMYUSER"
PASSWORD="DUMMYPASS"

# local directory containing source backup file
SOURCEFILES="/Users/harrold/Desktop/FOLDER/ftp-test"

# remote server directory path in which backup needs to be put in
BACKUPDIRCTORY="/folder/subfolder"

# login to remote server
ftp -n -i $SERVER <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
cd $BACKUPDIRCTORY
bin
lcd $SOURCEFILES
mput *
quit
EOF
```

However, **I want it to work using crontab** so it does the job every minute. This is how I did it with `% crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * /Users/harrold/bin/ftp_automate.sh >> /Users/harrold/bin/logs/ftp.log 2>&1
```

**Any idea why I'm getting the ftp command not found error?**

By the way, my script is placed inside `/Users/harrold/bin`.

Comment: Is `ftp` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @HKT : Why is this tagged zsh, when it is a bash script?

Comment: @Mureinik I am not using $PATH variable in any of the steps I did. Should I put it somewhere? Sorry still a newbie.

Comment: Also, look out for cron-overrun. (once per minute is very frequent)

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinPrikryl you are a lifesaver! Finally got to understand what to do with $PATH and the link provided some additional details I needed on my script. Cron job works now!

Answer (score 0):

I got it now!

I just had to **add the full path of ftp** on my script, as in:

```
/usr/local/bin/ftp -n -i $SERVER <<EOF
```

And additionally, I had to **add ftp $PATH on my bash profile** `vi .bash_profile` on my home directory (e.g. /Users/harrold)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/ftp:$PATH"
```

For the changes to take effect, I had to **reload my profile** with `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Adding `/usr/local/bin/ftp` to your `PATH` is definitely an error; the entries you add should be directories, not individual files.